# Handle background task every second in both android and ios with react native

Tags: android, react-native, background-process

I want to process background task to send location data every second to server,
I tried a few libraries but it doesn't work with 1s cycle
I read some articles that ios is very strict about this
Currently, is there any way I can make this work well on both android and ios?

Comment: 1 sec is a very bad approach. for sending location you can check, react native https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation

Its a paid library but its good and accurate

Comment: Think about battery consumption due to 1s cycle, phone battery will die soon.

Comment: Hi @GauravRoy, after researching, I still don't know how this library sends location data to the server?